# R data frames are not using Zeppelin's built-in visualizations

Tags: r, apache-zeppelin

In the R interpreter documentation [1], it shows that returning data frames will result in Zeppelin using the built in visualizations.

```
%spark.r
data(mtcars)
mtcars
```

[image: Zeppelin working built in visualization]

But when I try to do this with both Zeppelin `v0.7.3` & `v0.8.0-SNAPSHOT`, the output is instead a text representation of the R data frame.

[image: Zeppelin not working built in visualization]

[1] https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/interpreter/r.html

Comment: Hi, it looks like a bug. If you don't mind could you create an issue so that other contributors know about the issue and try to fix it? - https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ZEPPELIN

Comment: Awesome I opened it up here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-3000